# GUIでの操作だけでアプリが開発できるサービスがあるのですが、その理由がわかりません。（構文解析などが関係しうるのかもしれませんが）

Tags: android, java, ruby, objective-c, xcode

`appinventor`というweb上で、好きなパーツをはめていくだけで
手軽にAndroidアプリが作れるものがあります。

http://www.atmarkit.co.jp/ait/articles/1103/15/news087.html

手軽でびっくりしたのですが、
androidアプリとして動く(apkファイルを作成する)までの流れが理解しきれず困っております。

```
GUIで操作及び、ブロックのロジックを設定する
↓
ブラウザベースのサービスなので、
そのロジックをもとに、javascriptでjavaのスクリプトに変換（翻訳？）する
↓
GUIの部分はどういうプロセスを踏んでかは不明だが、xmlファイルに変換し、ボタンなどの位置を記憶する
↓
apkファイル生成
```

といった漠然としたイメージは持っております。

特にわからないのは、どうして、ブラウザ上で作成したロジックがandroidアプリで動くようになているのかという点です。

前述のとおり、何かしらの方法で翻訳しているのだと思うのですが、
ただ翻訳するだけでなく、javaのファイルとして生成しなければいけないと思います。

その部分が私の今の理解度では追いついておらず、ブラックボックス化しております。

ソースコードを呼んだり、ググったりしていたのですが、よくわからず、質問させていただきました。
https://github.com/mit-cml/appinventor-sources

興味本位の質問ではありますが、すごく面白いないようなので、車輪の開発にはなりますが、
自分でも同じようなことができるようになりたいと思っております。

そのために何が必要なのかも差支えがなければ教えていただけると幸いです。

拙い知識ではありますが

- 構文解析器
- コンパイル

などが肝になるのかなと思っております。

また、少し話がそれますが、
`rubymotion`という、rubyの文法で、iOS と Android のモバイルアプリが開発できる言語？
があります。

こういうのも今回の質問内容に類似しており、気になるところではあります。

rubyの文法で書いたロジックを何かしらの形で翻訳し、javaやobjective-cに変換するのだと思うのですが、ここでいうところのその変換方法が何なのかがわかりませんでした。

不足事項などは都度追記させていただきます。
何卒よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 4):

まず、ブラウザ上のJavascriptではUIのレイアウトとブロックの配置を行うエディタ、そしてXMLや後述するYAIL言語への変換を行います。このスクリプトは単純なJavascriptの他に、Javaで書かれたプログラムを[GWT](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Web_Toolkit)というツールで変換したものも含まれています。

プロジェクトをエクスポートする際はXMLを固めたzipになっていますが、デバッグやビルドの際に使われるのはもうひとつの[YAIL](https://github.com/mit-cml/appinventor-sources/blob/master/appinventor/blocklyeditor/src/generators/yail.js)（Young Android Intermediate Language）という言語です。これはAppInventor独自の[Scheme](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scheme)風のプログラミング言語で、UIもブロックもこの言語に変換され、Android端末で動かしたYAILインタプリタで動作します。このインタプリタは、Java上のScheme実装である[Kawa](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kawa)で実装されています。

apkファイルをダウンロードする時には、YAILコードとリソースをビルドサーバーに送り、それらとYAILインタプリタを合体してapkにします。ビルド処理の実装は[このあたりに](https://github.com/mit-cml/appinventor-sources/blob/master/appinventor/buildserver/src/com/google/appinventor/buildserver/Compiler.java)。

というわけで、Javaのソースコードやバイトコードを自ら生成しているわけではありません。

一般にAndroid向けにコンパイルするというとJavaバイトコードを生成するわけですが、Java以外の言語でAndroidアプリを作る方法を考えると、

- Javaでインタプリタを実装する
- Javaのソースコードに変換する
- Javaバイトコードへのコンパイラを実装する（Kawaとか）
- Javaバイトコードへのコンパイルができる、別の言語を経由する（Kawaを経由するYAIL）
- バイトコードではなく、ネイティブコードを生成する（Rubymotionなど）
  <sub>といってもLLVM使えば機械語を直接がりがり書く必要はないとかそういう</sub>

と、結構色んなパターンがあります。できることやパフォーマンス、難易度に大きく差があります。

ちなみにこれはどう出力するかの話です。変換元となるプログラムを読み取る処理は別途考える必要がありますが、そこで出てくるのか構文解析などのプロセスです。

参考

- [App Inventor Developer Overview](https://docs.google.com/a/6lab.org/document/d/1hIvAtbNx-eiIJcTA2LLPQOawctiGIpnnt0AvfgnKBok/pub)
- [what computer programming language is the app builder? - Google グループ](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mitappinventortest/cMkhyGqvFFA)

Comment: 具体的に書いていただき有難うございます。私の知識不足のため、すべてを理解しきれておりませんが、一文一文反芻し、理解していきたいと思います。

私は普段、rubyやpythonで実装をしております。
そのため、unaristのJava以外の言語でAndroidアプリを作る方法に興味があります。

ご提案いただいた手法でいうところの
「バイトコードではなく、ネイティブコードを生成する」を用いて？
ruby -> jruby
python -> Jython

を使用する事でできるのでしょうか？

rubymotionがjrubyを使用しているのかどうかはわかりませんが。

また、上記内容は私の理解不足で、齟齬があるかもしれません・・・。


> 変換元となるプログラムを読み取る処理は別途考える必要がありますが、そこで出てくるのか構文解析などのプロセスです。

ここでいうところの変換元となるプログラムを読み取る処理というのは、rubyやpythonという認識であってますでしょうか？(もし、rubyやpythonでプログラムを組んだ場合)

ここも理解不足で申し訳ありませんが、仮にpythonの構文解析をしたい場合、以下のようなところを参考すればいいでしょうか？

http://qiita.com/shinsa82/items/94d800df630e63511014

Comment: @zyosh JrubyはRubyインタプリタ・コンパイラのJava実装ですから、箇条書きの1番目と3番目かと思います。ネイティブコード（いわゆる機械語）生成はできません。また、そのQiita記事はPythonで何らかの構文解析をする方法であり、Pythonプログラムの構文解析とは無関係です。 / Javaコンパイラの仕組みはこの辺とかどうでしょう http://www.atmarkit.co.jp/ait/articles/0612/02/news016_2.html あとは最近だとプログラミング言語を作ることを題材にした書籍もありますから、そういったものを読まれると大筋が理解しやすくなるかもしれません。そういった資料を読んで、ご自身で調べても理解できないとなったら、また改めて質問していただければと思います。

Comment: ご回答有難うございます。コンパイラの仕組み等、きちんと理解しきれていなかったので、ご共有頂きましたURLなどを元に、勉強したいと思います。
また、プログラミング言語を作る書籍もいろいろとありました。
以下のような書籍のことでよろしいですよね？
http://www.amazon.co.jp/dp/4774149748/ref=pd_lpo_sbs_dp_ss_1?pf_rd_p=187205609&pf_rd_s=lpo-top-stripe&pf_rd_t=201&pf_rd_i=4774138959&pf_rd_m=AN1VRQENFRJN5&pf_rd_r=0CD4XCTXB6NWPKB28RGS


また、こういうの

http://www.amazon.co.jp/%E3%83%97%E3%83%AD%E3%82%B0%E3%83%A9%E3%83%9F%E3%83%B3%E3%82%B0%E8%A8%80%E8%AA%9E%E3%82%92%E4%BD%9C%E3%82%8B-%E5%89%8D%E6%A9%8B-%E5%92%8C%E5%BC%A5/dp/4774138959

こういうのやネット記事などを参照し、言語を作る部分についても勉強しようと思います。課題が見えてきましたので、とても感謝しております。

Comment: スクリプト言語の作り方 については今回の要件とは少しずれてしまってますでしょうか・・・。rubyやpythonをやっている身としては、とっかかりとしていいかなと思い。

Answer (score 1):

RubyMotion の場合は、JavaやObjective Cへの変換は行わずに直接バイナリ (より正確に言えば、LLVMのバイトコード) を出力します。つまり、Rubyコンパイラとして動作します。